# Goutte - dom crawler - remove node

Tags: php, symfony, dom, web-crawler, goutte

I have html on my site (http://testsite.com/test.php) :

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     <a href="/test.php">click</a>
     <span>back</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     <a href="/test.php">click</a>
     <span>back</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like receive:

```
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     <a href="/test.php">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
     <a href="/test.php">click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So i would like remove span. 
I use Goutte in Symfony2 based on http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html :

```
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://testsite.com/test.php');

    $crawler->filter('.first .second')->each(function ($node) {
        //??????
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

As [explained in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html):

> The DomCrawler component eases DOM navigation for HTML and XML documents.

and also:

> While possible, the DomCrawler component is not designed for manipulation of the DOM or re-dumping HTML/XML.

DomCrawler is designed to extract details from DOM documents rather than modifying them.

**However...**

Since PHP passes objects by reference, and *Crawler* is basically a wrapper for [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)s, it's technically possible to modify the underlying DOM document:

```php
// will remove all span nodes inside .second nodes
$crawler->filter('html .content h2')->each(function (Crawler $crawler) {
    foreach ($crawler as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
});
```

Here's a working example: https://gist.github.com/jakzal/8dd52d3df9a49c1e5922

Comment: It throws me error of Undefined variable: crawler,then i have use($crawler) but it doen't work for me

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. For the sake of improving the answer, I'd recommend disambiguating `$node` from the closure and `$node` from the `foreach()`. The error I'm getting ig `Error: Call to a member function removeChild() on null`. Happy to upvote once this is resolved and the example works.

Comment: While your gist example is working, this example is not due to the aforementioned param problem.

Comment: Don't know what happened there. Updated my answer with the correct example. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

`To remove a node the anonymous function must return false.`

Just return false inside the reducer and the $node will be deleted.

Comment: Inside the _reducer_, not just any closure.